# Automate Cognos 11 -> PowerBI (with limited privileges)

Tags: powerbi, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Desk Jockey here with the ability to write, schedule, and run reports. Although I have reached out to my IT for a solution, I'd rather not wait - especially because they may tell me that they won't.

I have been fiercely trying to automate the ability to take data that I have access to in Cognos and get it into PowerBI.

Things I CANNOT do (but presumably work)

- schedule a report to run and save a csv file to a networked folder (option not enabled for me).
- give PowerBI direct access to the data in question (not my role)
- connect PowerBI to Cognos. There is no native way for PowerBI to do this, but there are tools which enable it. However, I lack the permissions and authority to do that.

Things I have tried:

- I can create a URL which which directly passes the parameters and runs the report in any format

-- I then tried accessing the web page via PowerBIs get data from web functionality...but at best when it loads the page the "frame" around the data loads (but not the data...yet) so PowerBI cannot grab it. I suspect if there were some way to tell it to "wait" until everything loaded, it would work.

-- I tried running it as a csv file to download. But, again, the link is not directly to the file, but to a landing page which then starts the download. This is beyond my ability to automate as the baked in tools need a link to the file, not a link to the page which starts the download. Additionally, it is beyond my ability to ascertain what the "direct" link to the report is.

-- Access it via an API call. Cool: Cognos has an API. Uncool: I couldn't get anything to work. I think it is either disabled or I dont have permissions. (OR I just dont know enough to even test if it is working).

-- Trying any of the above with some combination of Cognos's scheduling features.

-- Trying any of the above with a "report view" instead of a report.

Comment: Using Cognos Analytics as an ETL tool is a horrible idea.  Cognos is not an ETL tool, nor is it a data source.  You should have access to the data regardless of which reporting tool you are using.  (So, ultimately, "give Power BI direct access to the data in question" is the correct answer.)  Maybe a lot of work has gone into the Cognos models to ensure you get correct data in an easy to use way -- and that work has not yet been done in the Power BI environment.  So, maybe you just need to wait for that to happen.

Comment: @dougp I appreciate the comment, sadly I am not IT and the company is large. This means if I want to get work done, I have to do it by any means available. When all IT gives you is a hammer, everything is a nail.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378  Maybe first tell us what you actually need to do and why you think you need to use Power BI.  Cognos can probably produce the report you need.  Using one reporting tool to produce data to feed another reporting tool doesn't seem valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Cognos as ETL for the power Bi, use the Cognos to create your reports. You will do your work more easily and faster.

Comment: This does no solve the users question, and the user may have reasons that they have use PBI rather than cosmos. You can find more information on how to write good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer